# MageReport.com reports patch not applied, but it has been

Tags: patches

MageReport.com reports a client website does not have Security patch 6788 applied.

I have applied this patch more than once, and MageReport.com continues to report that it has not been applied.

I noticed that /public_html/.htaccess.sample was missing, so I uploaded it, applied the patch again, and MageReport.com still reports the patch is missing.

When I run the patch in Putty SSH shell, I receive the output:

```
PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 127                                 : not found
PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 127                                 : not found
PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 0:                                  not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file .htaccess
Hunk #1 FAILED at 207.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file .htaccess.sample
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 291 (offset -7 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
checking file cron.php
checking file errors/processor.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
checking file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
checking file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

I am not skilled to ensure this patch is applied successfully.

Help appreciated.

Running Magento 1.9.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put .htaccess and .htaccess.sample file from default Magento version 1.9.1.0 and try to patch again.

Also if you have made any changes to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php take it from default version of Magento.

Comment: Beautiful! The default `.htaccess` was missing - there was a custom `.htaccess` file there. Uploading the default meant the patch reported as being applied successfully. Thank you Akhilesh!

Answer (score 1):

There's some errors at the top when you apply the patch

> PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 127                                 : not found
>
> PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 127                                 : not found
>
> PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.0_v1-2015-10-27-09-06-11.sh: 0:                                  not found
>
> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>
> -e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

To fix this, try running the patches using the '**bash**' command, instead of '**sh**'. The Magento patches don't run that well if your '**sh**' isn't linked to '**bash**'. This is the case on a lot of servers, but isn't something Magento has taken into consideration.

As for the reason it's reported as uninstalled, we found out that there are several reasons why Patch 6788 comes out as uninstalled on Magereport.com, so we recommend you to check the following:

- <strike>Check if the patch is installed in the correct directory;</strike> This looks to be done, as the patch applies
- <strike>Check your shops’ .htaccess. If you’ve made any adjustements in your .htaccess, it’s possible the patch is only partially installed;</strike> *Looks good, since all the patches applied.*
- <strike>Using a Magento version older them Magento 1.6.1.0? Update to a more recent version. When patching Magento versions older then Magento 1.6.1.0, certain redirects aren’t added.</strike> Looks like you're running on 1.9.1.0
- Reload your opcode cache, webserver, php-fpm process and possible other caches. The old code might be still be active;
- When compilation is enabled in the backend of your Magento, SUPEE-6482 doesn’t work properly. Disable compilation (navigate to System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button) to make sure the patch works. After disabling compilation, check your site with magereport.com again. If the check still comes out as not installed, try re-compiling.

Comment: Thanks for your help Cipriano. How do I `Reload your opcode cache, webserver, php-fpm process and possible other caches` ? I refreshed all caches, and restarted Apache. Magento is not compiled. MageReport still reports the patch is missing.